# Concerning the maximum modulus principle. Need some hints.

Tags: complex-analysis

*Let $f:\mathbb{\overline{D}}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a non-constant function continuous on $\mathbb{\overline{D}}$ and analytic in $\mathbb{D}$. Show that if $|f(z)-1|=1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$ then $f(z)\neq0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$.*

I can understand that the solution to this problem must deal with the maximum modulus principle. But I cannot find the starting point. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Look at the function $g \colon z \mapsto f(z) - 1$. Suppose $f$ had a zero inside $\mathbb{D}$. What does the maximum modulus principle then say about $g$?

Comment: @DanielFischer could you check the following answer?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(z_0)=0$ for some $z_0\in\mathbb{D}$. Define $g:\mathbb{\overline{D}}\to{\mathbb{C}}$ by $g(z)=f(z)-1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{\overline{D}}$. Then since $\mathbb{D}$ is a bounded domain the maximum of $|g|$ occurs on its boundary. But by supposition $|g(z)|=1$ on the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$. Therefore $|g(z)|\leq1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{\overline{D}}$. But this maximum of $|g|$ occurs inside $\mathbb{D}$ because $|g(z_0)|=1$. Hence by the maximum modulus principle $g$ must be constant in $\mathbb{D}$ and by continuity of $g$ it follows that $g$ is constant in $\mathbb{\overline{D}}$. Therefore $f$ is constant in $\mathbb{\overline{D}}$ which is a contradiction. Hence the result.

Comment: Yup, that's the argument.